# How to set the size of thumbnail in legend for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set the size of thumbnail/icon in the legend for matplotlib? one way is to manipulate the text size in legend so that the icon would look relatively big/small using `plt.setp(fig.gca().get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='15')`.

Is there any direct way to change the size of the thumbnail/icon representing the plot in the legend?

```
import numpy as np
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex = True)
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 25}
plt.rc('font', **font)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.random.randn(10)
ax.errorbar(a, b, yerr=0.5, fmt='o', color='g', ecolor='g', capthick=1, linestyle = '-', linewidth=2, elinewidth=1, label = "Test")
legend = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=2, ncol=6, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.2)
fig.set_size_inches(14.5, 10.5)
plt.savefig('/Users/Cupitor/Test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html ?  You can control this by passing in custom handler classes or by passing in args to the default ones.

Comment: Yes. I was wondering the exact arg that I should pass in... which @CTZhu helped me with it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `markerscale` parameter for this. >1 value means plot marker larger than that's on the actual plot, i.e.:

```
legend = plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=2, 
                    ncol=6, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.2,
                    markerscale=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: There is  a problem with your suggestion that I just figured out! It just makes the centre of the icon smaller but not the whole green thumbnail... i.e. just the green circle in the middle and not the confidence intervals!